# Method doesn't display UIImageView (iOS XCode Cocoa touch)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8, xcode6

I'd like to have a method display an image. My view controller calls the method:

```
eduPopup *thisEduPopup = [[eduPopup alloc] init];
[thisEduPopup displayPopup];
```

In the method I have:

```
-(void) displayPopup {

   UIImageView *thisImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
   thisImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"referral_eduscreen_text_solid.png"];
   thisImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, thisImage.image.size.width, thisImage.image.size.height);
   [self.superview addSubview:thisImage];
}
```

...but I get nothing. Is self.superview the right reference? What I should be putting there?

Comment: why are you adding a subview to the superview? What is your view hierarchy like? If you're just trying to display a popup on top of your current view, why not [self.view addSubview:thisImage] ?

Comment: What I did was have the function return and UIView, and the parent does EduPopup *thisEduPopup = [[EduPopup alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController.view addSubview: [thisEduPopup displayEduPopup]];